# Is there any way to modify project structure based on git branch?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a git repository composed of several directories.

These directories contain projects in different programming languages, python/java/scala/yaml.
There are a lot of different directories, and so I need modules to set up specific SDKs for the different modules.

My problem is that whenever I switch branches, some of the modules of my projects no longer exist and are left empty (for example it's an old branch and they did not exist back then) and I need to reimport some old ones (they became obsolete and got deleted).

Here is an example:

On branch B1

```
project
       \ dir X (with specific module for specific settings)
       |-dir Y
       |-dir Z
```

On branch B2

```
project
       \ dir A (with specific module for specific settings)
       |-dir Y
       |-dir Z
```

Whenever switching from B1 to B2, I need to import module A and have an empty module X.
Whenever switching from B2 to B1, I need to import module X and have an empty module A.

Would there be any way for me to link the submodules of my project to git so that they get added/deleted depending on my git actions?

Another way to put it is: **Is there any way to modify project structure based on git branch?**

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question, but doesn't the "Synchronize Project" functionality after e.g. a `checkout` or `stash` action do just what you ask?

Comment: Well I tried, but it does not work. I think the problem is that I have submodules in the project with specific settings